# NAV misplaced on Chrome only on the first load

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, nav

I encounter a little problem with the header of my website on Google Chrome.
The first time the webpage is loaded, the navigation bar is misplaced, but then if I refresh the page, the navigation bar is well-placed. I don't get why this bug keeps occuring to me and friends who use Google Chrome.

This is how it appears on the first load of the page (misplaced) :
[image: First load of the website on Chrome]

And this is how it looks after refreshing the page (well-placed) :
[image: After refreshing the page on Chrome]

Now this is the HTML description of the header :

```
<header>
    <div id="head1">
        <h1>Léo Dupont</h1>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">E1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">E2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">E3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">E4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">E5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <h2>ESIEE Paris - Deuxième année</h2>
</header>
```

And this is the CSS part :

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine:700);

body {
    margin:0;
}

/* HEADER */
header, header h1, header h2 {
    color:white;
    margin:0;
}

/* HEADER : high */
header #head1 {
    height:80px;
    background-color:#006400;
}
header h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family:'Tangerine', cursive;
    font-size:100px;
}

/* HEADER : low */
header h2 {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#008000;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
}

/* HEADER : NAVIGATION */
header nav {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
        right:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
header nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
header nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:30px;
    width:55px;
    height:55px;
    background:white;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:none;
    color:#fff;
}
header nav li a {
    position: relative;
        top: 18px;
        left: 16px;
    font:bold 14pt Arial;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
```

Does someone have an idea of how I could fix this ?

Comment: Does it go away if you remove the Google font?

Comment: No, the bug remains even without the @import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle containing your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/rfm4u/

Please do this when asking these sorts of questions - it makes it easier to help.

I can't explain why you're sometimes seeing one behavior vs the other. I think the inconsistency may very well be an issue with Chrome's rendering engine.  I inspected the `<nav>` element in Chrome's dev tools and flipped the `display: inline-block;` property on and off. When I flipped it off, I saw the nav menu jump to the bottom in exactly the way you had it in the first screenshot, but the weird thing is, after setting it back to on, it didn't jump back - it just stayed there. Toggling the property afterward didn't do anything.

However, I see how you're currently positioning the `<nav>` element and noticed that you're not really actually controlling its vertical position.  You might think the `vertical-align: middle` bit is controlling it, but since you're using absolute positioning on it, you've taken that `<nav>` element out of normal document flow, so you're not actually vertically centering it relative to the `<div id="head1">` like you might think.  The vertical-align property is confusing: you may want to take a look at [this](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/).

There are a couple possible fixes - pick the one you like best.

**Approach 1: Explicitly set the vertical position**

Just add a `top: 5px;` (or whatever value you prefer) on the `header nav` style. Now you're explicitly controlling the position, instead of leaving it up to chance (or the browser's quirky rendering engine).

What you lose is the vertical centering, which, judging from the code, is something you wanted. With this approach, if you ever change the height on your `<div id="head1">`, you would need to manually tweak the nav positioning as well.

**Approach 2: Use the absolute vertical centering technique**

There is a trick you can use to vertically center content regardless of the container's size.  There's a good in-depth article on it here:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

In your case, this will require a minor tweak since you don't actually want to center the `<nav>` horizontally relative to the `<div id="head1">` - you want it to stay to the right, so you would just need to leave off the `left: 0;` part.

Here's what you need to do to apply this technique.

1. Set the `position: relative;` property on the `header #head1` style. This is required because you want to vertically center the `<nav>` relative to the `<div id="head1">`, not `<body>`. In case you aren't aware of how relative position works, all you need to remember is:

> [An element with relative positioning gives you the control to absolutely position children elements inside of it](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

1. Declare an explicit height on the `header nav` using something like `height: 87px;`. This is required for the aforementioned trick to work (though there are some ways around it mentioned in the article above).
2. Set the `top`, `bottom`, and `right` properties to 0 on the `header nav` (note we're leaving out `left: 0` to avoid centering it horizontally), and also set the `margin: auto;` property, as described in the technique.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/ajfUK/2/

You can try changing the height on the `#head1` element in Chrome's dev tools, and observe that the `<nav>` stays vertically centered.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will use the Approach n°1 for now as it is enough for the design as it is. But I will remember the Approach n°2, which is really useful. Thanks for the jsfiddle.net tip too.